# How to call bash script using c# application hosted in docker and that will make changes to the host machine

Tags: c#, bash, docker

I am calling some bash scripts like changing the unix password for a user using C#. This is working fine when i directly run my C# console application in unix.

But now i have created docker for the console application and running the same bash script. This is not working and giving some error command not found.

So is there a option to call this script using c# application which is hosted in docker and make the changes on to the host machine after executing the script.

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: If the process is running in a container, it _can't_ make changes to the host system like this.  It needs to run outside the container (and potentially as root).

Comment: @DavidMaze Process will be running in a container only but is there any posibility to make changes to host system from the process which is running in a docker container

Comment: Being able to escape the container like this would be a massive security issue, especially if you're able to edit security-critical files like `/etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 0):

Re-think your architecture. It is not going to work this way at all.

What you probably want to do is to:

1. Ensure your host can access your docker network.
2. Create a service on the host machine that will accept a request (REST, SOAP, whatever you want) from your container on the docker and
3. Execute the script on the host machine once that request is received.

If you don't mind, pray enlighten us on the purpose of such a script, so we can see if there is a better way of doing this, since this looks very suspicious and should be re-modeled.